# Пагинация элементов

Tags: jquery

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <ul>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- эти элементы после перехода на вторую страницу скрываем, и показываем после перехода обратно на первую -->

<div class="block pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li> 
    <li class="element">Я элемент 4 (страница2)</li> <!--переход на новую страницу -->
    <li class="element">Я элемент 5 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 6 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 7 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 8 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 9 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 10 (страница3)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button type="submit">Предыдущая страница</button>
  <button type="submit">Следующая страница</button>
</div>
```

Есть 2 блока, первый должен показываться только на первой странице, а второй уже подстраиваться под пагинацию, в разметке все расписал, первая страница состоит из 3 элементов, а последующие из 6 элементов.

Первый блок должен быть виден только на первой странице.
Надеюсь достаточно подробно и понятливо объяснил.

Comment: почему jquery? стройте ссылки на стороне сервера

Comment: @teran можете подсказать каким образом? передам разработчику

Comment: @teran и это не статичный элемент, это динамичные, там может быть 3 элемента , а может быть 1000, и все они уникальны

Comment: я и не говорил, что он статичный. я лишь спросил, почему вы делаете пагинацию на js, обычно это реализуется на серверной стороне средствами php/c#/ и т.п. 
Или это не пагинация в прямом смысле слова? а просто данамическое переключение элементов некоторое?

Comment: под пагинацией я имел имеено динамичное переключение элементов )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам требуется настроить отображение этих элементов в зависимости от номера страницы на jquery, то посмотрите на код ниже. в противном случае мне не совсем ясна суть задачи.

```js
var page = 1;
    totalPages = 3;

$(function(){
    updatePages();
});

$("#next, #prev").click(function(){
    
    var bId = $(this).attr('id');
    bId == "next" ? page++ : page--;
    if(page < 1) page = 1;
    if(page > totalPages) page = totalPages;   
    
    updatePages();
});

function updatePages(){   
   $(".pagination li.element")
      .removeClass('current')
      .filter("[data-page=" + page+"]")
          .addClass('current');
          
   $("#first-page").toggle(page == 1);
      
}
```

```css
li.element { display: none; }
li.element.current {display: block; }


#first-page { background-color: #eee; }
#first-page .element { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="first-page">
  <ul>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- эти элементы после перехода на вторую страницу скрываем, и показываем после перехода обратно на первую -->

<div class="block pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="element" data-page="1">Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element" data-page="1">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element" data-page="1">Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li> 
    <li class="element" data-page="2">Я элемент 4 (страница2)</li> <!--переход на новую страницу -->
    <li class="element" data-page="2">Я элемент 5 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" data-page="2">Я элемент 6 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" data-page="2">Я элемент 7 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" data-page="2">Я элемент 8 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" data-page="3">Я элемент 9 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element" data-page="3">Я элемент 10 (страница3)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="prev">Предыдущая страница</button>
  <button id="next">Следующая страница</button>
</div>
```

**дополнение**

Если следовать правилу, что на первой странице 3 элемента, а на остальных по 6, то в целом `data-page` атрибут, конечно, не нужен (я бы его правда все равно сделал, т.к. это куда удобнее и функциональнее). Решение может быт таким:

```js
var page = 1;
    totalPages = 3;

$(function(){
    updatePages();
});

$("#next, #prev").click(function(){
    
    var bId = $(this).attr('id');
    bId == "next" ? page++ : page--;
    if(page < 1) page = 1;
    if(page > totalPages) page = totalPages;   
    
    updatePages();
});

function updatePages(){   
   var offset = -3 + (page-1)*6; 
   $(".pagination li.element")
      .removeClass('current')
      .slice(offset < 0 ? 0 : offset, offset + 6)
          .addClass('current');
          
   $("#first-page").toggle(page == 1);
      
}
```

```css
li.element { display: none; }
li.element.current {display: block; }


#first-page { background-color: #eee; }
#first-page .element { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" id="first-page">
  <ul>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- эти элементы после перехода на вторую страницу скрываем, и показываем после перехода обратно на первую -->

<div class="block pagination">
  <ul>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 1 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element">Я элемент 2 (страница1)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 3 (страница1)</li> 
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 4 (страница2)</li> <!--переход на новую страницу -->
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 5 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 6 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 7 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 8 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 9 (страница2)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 10 (страница3)</li>
    <li class="element" >Я элемент 11 (страница3)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="prev">Предыдущая страница</button>
  <button id="next">Следующая страница</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть решение без аттрибута data-page? Потому-что элементы приходят с сервера в массиве, я перебираю массив и вывожу элементы без "data-page"

Comment: @kiLLro если по 3/6/6/6.... элементов то дополнил ответ. в противном случае не ясно как переключать.

Comment: а что если кол-во страниц и элементов динамичное?

Comment: @kiLLro дак в любом случае необходимо как то сформлировать критерии что и на какой странице показыается, по какому принципу. Без этого задачу не решить.

Comment: А что если формулу сделать которая количество страниц высчитывает? Количество элементов может быть разное, от 1 до ~

Comment: Предположение по формуле [totalPages =  (n - 3) / 6]  где  n - кол-во элементов

Comment: Пришел вот к такой формуле: https://jsfiddle.net/zc6qbLc2/
Можно как-нибудь усовершенствовать?

Comment: @kiLLro я бы сказал так `totalPages = Math.ceil((3 + elements_length)/page_elements);` где `elements_length = $(".pagination .element").length;`

Comment: Супер! Спасибо, то что нужно.